# Describe MANIFEST.MF with classpath like java -cp

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a command line Java application, which has dependencies to other libs/jars. Therefore I'm running the application with the `-cp`, e.g. `java -cp libs/* <package.MainClass> <args>`.

What I'm trying to do is to copy the dependency libs/jars in my Java application and describing correctly the MANIFEST.MF with the reason that I don't need the option `-cp libs/*` anymore.

My project is  a maven project, therefore I'm using the `maven-assembly-plugin` to copy the libs in my JAR and describing the MANIFEST.MF. What I'm right now is the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>dist</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And my MANIFEST.MF looks like this atm:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: user
Class-Path: lib/deps_A.jar lib/deps_B.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_202
Main-Class: MainClass
```

My Question is: How can describe the MANIFEST.MF file, so that I run my application with `java -jar <my-jar-application.jar> <args>`?

Comment: From what you posted, the contents of the `MANIFEST.MF` file looks correct and the `java` command also looks correct. I'm guessing an error is occurring when you try running your `java` command. Maybe post the error you are getting?

Comment: @Abra I'm not getting any errors, but my application does work properly. And when I'm printing the content of the classpath `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getURLs()`, there are no lib jars listed.

Comment: Then I suggest you describe the problem. I assume your program is producing unexpected output. Tell us what you expect and what you are actually getting.

Comment: The only thing what I can describe without exposing company-internal information is, that I want to be able to list the JARs with `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getURLs()`. If the libs JARs are not visible on the classpath, then my application does not work properly due to the missing services of the jars.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest entries are not listed among the URLs of the *SystemClassLoader*.

You have to manually get them from the manifest file.

```java
            ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            if (cl instanceof URLClassLoader) {
                URLClassLoader ucl = (URLClassLoader) cl;
                URL[] urLs = ucl.getURLs();
                for (URL url : urLs) {
                    File file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile()));

                    try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file)){
                        Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
                        String attrs = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue(Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH.toString());
                        if(attrs!=null) {
                            String[] splits = attrs.split(" ");
                            for (String split:  splits) {
                                // This is the name of the jar referenced in manifest.
                                System.out.println(split);
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println(file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I took inspiration from [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) lib, you can also check the sources of [Classpath](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.java) class.